# Who is Johanna in this Joan Baez song - The Winds of the Old Days

Tags: folk, country

In [this](https://youtu.be/nDtU81tyCZk) song, The Winds of the Old Days, by Joan Baez, the last stanza is:

> And get you down to the harbor now
>
> Most of the sour grapes are gone from the bough
>
> Ghosts of Johanna will visit you there
>
> And the winds of the old days will blow through your hair

Who is Johanna?

Comment: I here "ghosts of the old days"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bob Dylan wrote a song called ["Visions of Johanna"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visions_of_Johanna) in 1965. Joan Baez was at the concert the first time he performed the song publicly and believed the lyrics referred to her. Presumably she is referring to herself in her song

Answer (score 4):

a plaintive remenisence about Joan's love for Bob Dylan about what they experienced together in the 60's. Obviously a human with great heart and soul. She depicts the poignant feelings that come flooding back when she reads about the "prince" returning to performing. This is a pretty accurate depiction of how deep feelings may seem buried but are only lurking just below our day to day existence. good effort.